# Disable/Hide InApp purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am about to deliver my free project to the iOS App Store.

However the associated provisioning portal AppId has GameCenter & InApp Purchases enabled.

I have not linked against the StoreKit framework & have not configured any InApp purchases.

Please can someone clarify whenever the user will see these options? I.e the plus symbol on the 'Buy Now' button?

Comment: The plus symbol on buy it now doesn't mean it has in-app purchase; it means that it's a universal application, i.e. it works on both the iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to @Jack Lawrence.

The Plus symbol actually represents 'Universal App' rather than In-App purchase